# Beach ball in Bluetooth in System Preference when trying to connect to Anne Pro 2 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, macos

I have trouble connecting to my Anne Pro 2 keyboard recently after the latest firmware update (see screenshot)

[image]

I have tried to deregister the device and register it again.

When I tried to connect to `28-ec-9a-9b-73-53` (presumably the AP2 keyboard), the Bluetooth pane froze and a beach ball appeared and kept spinning.

[image]

I have tried the 'Clean bind' in the AP2 utility:

[image]

then retried the connection, but it does not work.

What else can I try?